How can the call time displayed on the phone and the call time taken from the RS232 port of the Panasonic kx-tes824 switch overlap
The call time on the phone, for example, is 20 seconds, but the data retrieved from the switchboard is 30 seconds, which does not match the call time between the switchboard and the phone. (How to only calculate time when the called person picks up the phone and stop calculating time when the call ends so that the time on the phone and switchboard can match).
When the called person does not pick up the phone, the waiting time for the called person to pick up the phone until they do not pick up the phone, for example, is 40 seconds. After hanging up, the switchboard data still returns the call time as 40 seconds. (How to not display call time when the called person does not pick up).
Language and device
WinForms, Net Framework 4.7.2
Panasonic kx-tes824 switchboard
Thanks

using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TGTH
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        SerialPort serialPort;

        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

                serialPort = new SerialPort(
                    portName: "COM1",
                    baudRate: 9600,
                    parity: Parity.None,
                    dataBits: 8,
                    stopBits: StopBits.One
                )
                {
                    Handshake = Handshake.None,
                    DtrEnable = true,
                    RtsEnable = true,
                };
                serialPort.Open();
                serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
        }

        private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            
            string data = serialPort.ReadLine();

            string pattern = @"\b(\d{1,2}/\s?\d{1,2}/\d{2})\b";
            Match match = Regex.Match(data, pattern);
            DateTime parsedDate;

            string date = "", time = "", jack = "", phone = "", voice = "", line = "", code_call = "", destination = "";
            double totalCost = 0;

            string dateString = match.Groups[1].Value.Trim();
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, new string[] { "M/ d/yy", "MM/ d/yy", "M/dd/yy", "MM/dd/yy" }, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
            {
                string[] parts = data.Substring(match.Index + match.Length).Trim().Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                date = parsedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

                time = parts[0];
                DateTime parsedTime;
                DateTime.TryParseExact(time, "h:mmtt", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedTime);
                time = parsedTime.ToString("HH:mm");

                jack = parts[1];

                line = parts[2];
                line = "C" + line;

                phone = parts[3];

                voice = parts[4];
                voice = voice.Replace("'", ":").Replace("\"", "");
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
            AddDataToDataGridView(date, time, jack, phone, voice, line, code_call, destination, totalCost.ToString());
        }

        private void AddDataToDataGridView(string date, string time, string jack, string phone, string voice, string line, string code_call, string destination, string totalCost)
        {
            if (dgvDataCom.InvokeRequired)
            {
                dgvDataCom.Invoke(new Action(() => AddDataToDataGridView(date, time, jack, phone, voice, line, code_call, destination, totalCost)));
            }
            else
            {
                dgvDataCom.Rows.Add(date, time, jack, phone, voice, line, code_call, destination, totalCost);
            }
        }
    }
}



Seems like you're trying to reconcile the data from one source (the phone) with the data from a different source (the switchboard). The fact that a serial link is involved in obtaining the value from the second source is probably completely irrelevant. Just because software is involved doesn't mean this is a software problem. This seems to be an application problem. Where are the definitions for these data that you are comparing?

I am making call billing software using panasonic kx-tes824 switchboard. Works by using a phone line registered at a network operator in Vietnam (after registration, the fiber optic cable line will be pulled to your home and use that phone number to make calls) then Connect the phone line to the switchboard's CO port, the switchboard's Jack port will connect to the wired desk phone. The wired landline phone will be used to call other mobile phones and charge a fee, for example 1 minute = 1,000 VND. To retrieve call data from wired desk phones to the software, I use the rs232 port.

I use a landline phone to call a random cell phone number. When the call ends, the mobile phone returns for example 30 seconds and the switchboard call data is retrieved from the rs232 port, for example 40 seconds. The time does not match and the call is charged incorrectly
